# Install Selenium Server on redhat linux

Tags: linux, selenium, redhat, selenium-grid

I am trying to create a Selenium Grid project. I have done so on windows no problem, but now that I am trying to do so on redhat I am a little confused on where to download the server. My machine is headless so I cannot bring up a browser to go to the selenium home page and simply click the download button.

Anyone know the yum command or wget path needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this was an easy one. You can use

`wget http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar`

to get the jar file downloaded.

Then you can just use it setup your HUB and Nodes through the command line.

Answer (score 2):

One more way to download file using command line in Linux.

```
[root@ap4004 tmp]# curl -O http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 31.5M  100 31.5M    0     0  2783k      0  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:-- 2802k
```